# Python Networkx - Visualizing a distance matrix

Tags: python, graph, networkx, euclidean-distance

I'm tyring to use Networkx to visualize a distance matrix.  What I want is a graph where the edge length between nodes is proportional to the distance between them in the distance matrix.  I wrote the following code but it does not look like the resulting network takes the distance matrix into account at all.  For instance, there are a few nodes that have distance of zero between them and they are not close at all in the resulting graph.  How do I make this work?

```
names,data=loadDataSet()
#get distance matrix
dist_mat=cdist(data,data)

G=nx.from_numpy_matrix(dist_mat)

mapping=dict(zip(G.nodes(),names))
G = nx.relabel_nodes(G,mapping)

nx.draw(G)
pl.show()
```

Comment: Maybe some of the advice in the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513455/drawing-a-graph-or-a-network-from-a-distance-matrix
is useful?

Comment: Yes I saw that post and I tried to emulate the code, but perhaps it is not possible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drawing a graph or a network from a distance matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513455/drawing-a-graph-or-a-network-from-a-distance-matrix)