# Visualizing distance matrix as graph without edges in Python

Tags: python, numpy, graph, visualization, distance

I have a distance matrix between 500 items as a 500*500 numpy matrix.  I would like to visualize it as a graph of nodes (since it is a complete connected graph, there is no point in drawing edges) which respects the distance between nodes.

I saw many posts related to this question, but most of the answers are partly working/not working.

[Visualize distance matrix as a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911994/visualize-distance-matrix-as-a-graph)

[Drawing a graph or a network from a distance matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513455/drawing-a-graph-or-a-network-from-a-distance-matrix)

I know the fact that, it is not mathematically possible to visualize such a graph from the pairwise distance only.  But I am OK with an approximation result which works for any number of nodes.

Any help ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. `since it is a complete connected graph, there is no point in drawing edges` -  A graph without edges makes very little sense.

Comment: what i meant is, there will be too many edges. My ultimate aim is to see the clusters in the data.  I am Ok with edges.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911994) seems like an exact duplicate of what you're asking. What about the answer given there doesn't work? If you adjust this question to be a followup to the earlier question, rather than asking the same thing, it can be taken off hold.

Comment: Where does the matrix come from?  Are the distances consistent with Euclidean geometry, i.e. is there a configuration of 500 points in the plane such that the Euclidean distances between the points is your distance matrix (or at least an approximation thereof)?

Comment: Distance is cosine distance between the points, and hence it is consistent with euclidean geometry. the points lie in a n-dimensional plane.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the graph visualization in this paper: http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0123507 (Fig. 2).