# visualize pairwise similarity matrix which indicates geodesic distances

Tags: python, graph, graphviz, graph-visualization

In Python, I need to visualize a pairwise similarity matrix in a Graph. I want the nodes which are closer to be visualized by a closer distance. What I need is exactly what is mentioned in this link ([Drawing a graph or a network from a distance matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513455/drawing-a-graph-or-a-network-from-a-distance-matrix/27435898#27435898)) , but I get the following error, even if I install the package:

'requires pygraphviz ', 'http://networkx.lanl.gov/pygraphviz ', '(not available for Python3

Thanks,

Comment: It looks like you have an old version of pygraphviz; if you look at the download page (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygraphviz) it is compatible up to Python 3.4

Comment: The website for general pygraphviz information is http://pygraphviz.github.io/

Comment: Thanks guys, there is a single version of pygraphviz in the website, while the other download links give you the link to download the different Python version, not different version of pygraphviz, isnt it?