# Python – visualise correlation in data

Tags: python, graph, correlation

I have a dataframe and want to identify how the variables are correlated. I can get the correlation matrix easily using – `df.corr()`. I know I can easily plot the correlation matrix using `plt.matshow(df.corr())` or seaborn's `heatmap`, but I'm looking for something like this - [graph](https://d3ansictanv2wj.cloudfront.net/figure_3-5a3910aac95a46ff5b2022371a1fdd8c.jpg) 
[image]
taken from [here](https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/ideas-on-interpreting-machine-learning). In this image, the thicker the line connecting the variables is, the higher the correlation.

I did a few searches on stack and elsewhere but all of them are correlation matrices where the values have been replaced by colors. Is there a way to achieve the linked plot?

Comment: Look into the [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) package. Possible [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13514416/4098013)

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan, thanks. Looks like a duplicate.